# how to use qemu to emulate spi(a kind of Synchronous Serial Interface) flash device?

Tags: arm, qemu, spi

I want to use qemu to emulate spi device like m25p80 series. The is a source code mp25p80.c  in qemu project but I don't know how to use it.
Is there an example of using spi flash on the Arm platform?

Hope to get an answer

Comment: You question title shows that you probably don't know about SPI NOR and SPI NAND. The flash memory using different protocols. You need to clarify what exactly you. are trying to achieve.